# Where can you find wind tunnel visualization data online?

Tags: aerodynamics, experimental-aircraft, wind-tunnel

I was wondering if there was a repository of flow visualization results somewhere online, preferably of wing sections categorised in some manner.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you will find to a comprehensive, freely accessible source of data on this is the [NASA Technical Reports Server](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp). It is a search tool that gives you access to many NACA reports on various airfoils.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the ERCOFTAC Classic database collection at: http://cfd.mace.manchester.ac.uk/ercoftac/index.html

It is a comprehensive database used by fluid-dynamicist for model validation, and it contains many flow visualizations including a couple of wing test cases. Experimental data are free to download.